# I am facing a problem in my python kivy code

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

So i am writing my first python kivy code and came across this problem. Tried searching up but didn't quite understand how to solve it. can u please correct my code and tell me what's wrong?

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '400')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '150')

kv = Builder.load_file("krxls.kv")


class LoginPage(Screen):
    pass

class RegisterPage(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass



class KrxLS(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    KrxLS().run()
```

This is my kv file

```
WindowManager:
    LoginPage:
    RegisterPage:

<LoginPage>:
    name: "lp"
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: "Login!!"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: "Username"
            TextInput:
                multiline: "False"
            Label:
                text: "Password"
            TextInput:
                multiline: "False"
            Button:
                text: "Sign up"
                on_release: app.root.current = "rp"
            Button:
                text: "Sign in!"

<RegisterPage>:
    name: "rp"
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: "Register!!"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: "Username"
            TextInput:
                multiline: "False"
            Label:
                text: "Password"
            TextInput:
                multiline: "False"
            Button:
                text: "Sign in"
                on_release: app.root.current = "lp"
            Button:
                text: "Sign Up!"
```

i get this error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/randomman/PycharmProjects/Beginner/GUIDev/kivyGUI.py", line 12, in <module>
     kv = Builder.load_file("krxls.kv")
   File "/Users/randomman/PycharmProjects/Beginner/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "/Users/randomman/PycharmProjects/Beginner/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 399, in load_string
     widget = Factory.get(parser.root.name)(__no_builder=True)
   File "/Users/randomman/PycharmProjects/Beginner/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/factory.py", line 131, in __getattr__
     raise FactoryException('Unknown class <%s>' % name)
 kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <WindowManager>
```

Please help!!
i am learning kivy through youtube vids and tried following them but i got this error... I have already searched this up in google and haven't found a proper solution.

Comment: This is a total guess, but should the first line of your `.kv` file be `<WindowManager>` instead of `WindowManager`?

Comment: You have not defined a `WindowManager` class.

Comment: i have made ```WindowManager``` to ```<WindowManager>``` in the code and now im facing this error ```[CRITICAL] [Application ] No window is created. Terminating application run.```@MattDMo.
Im sorry, but what do you mean by "You have not defined a WindowManager class." Cause i have made that class in the python code. Thank you for your time :) @JohnAnderson

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your `WindowManager`:

```
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
```

before you load the `kv` file. A generally safe way to do the `kv` load is to call it inside the `build()` method, like this:

```
class KrxLS(App):
    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("krxls.kv")
        return kv
```